# Accessing music library in iPhone OS 3.0

Tags: iphone, media-player

My requirement is that i want to access the list of all the songs from the iPhone library.

I have included the MediaPlayer Framework in my project. So how to get the list of all the songs ???

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check out apple's AddMusic sample code, it has the entire thing.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/AddMusic/